# Callout Popups not showing documents preview

Tags: 2013, document-library, callouts

What do i need to do to have documents preview enabled with Callout popups. 
When i click the ... it popups the callout and some metadata info of the document but no preview of the document not even Microsoft docs.

Any ideas i think im missing something.
Cheers in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to have office webapps installed and configured on your SharePoint server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455%28v=office.15%29.aspx
http://melcher.it/2013/05/install-office-web-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-2013-with-pdf-preview/